# octave opens GUI when I type "octave" in terminal

Tags: octave

I have a problem:
installed octave and do not know why, every time I type octave in the terminal opens the GUI interface (gui --force-octave) Octave and not the terminal octave as is right. how can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SOF!  There is a correct answer available that you should consider accepting.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Octave 4.0, the GUI is the default:

> ** A graphical user interface is now the default when running Octave interactively.  The start-up option --no-gui will run the familiar command line interface...

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-4.0.html

Comment: very annoying update. I am not fan of GUIs in general. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this  **alias octave='octave --no-gui'**  to your ~/.bashrc file and every time you type octave, it opens in your terminal.

Good luck